# Как автоматически подсчитывать кол-во строк в таблице?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Допустим у меня есть таблица:

```
CREATE table products(id int primary key auto_increment, title varchar(64), sold tinyint default 0, owner_id int);
```

Сейчас несколько моих запросов, которые считают кол-во строк для каждого пользователя выглядят так:

```
--Общее кол-во товаров
SELECT owner_id, count(*) FROM products GROUP BY owner_id;
--Кол-во проданных товаров
SELECT owner_id, count(*) FROM products WHERE sold=1 GROUP BY owner_id;
--Кол-во товаров на продаже
SELECT owner_id, count(*) FROM products WHERE sold=0 GROUP BY owner_id;
```

*Все необходимые индексы есть

Но, появилась проблема - у некоторых пользователей есть больше 100 тысяч записей, и этот запрос может занимать 1-2 секунды (что непозволительно долго). Появилась идея создать отдельную таблицу, которая будет хранить в себе ID пользователя и кол-во товаров:

```
CREATE table products_count(owner_id int, count_sum int, extra_data varchar(8));
```

Но проблема в том, что в коде довольно много запросов, которые удаляют/меняют/добавляют записи в `products` и было бы довольно трудно изменить их все, чтобы автоматически считалось кол-во записей.

Возможно ли как-то, используя стандартные средства MySQL, при каждом измении/удалении/пополнении таблицы `products`, пересчитывать товары для отдельного пользователя (используя различные условия, вроде `sold=0`, `sold=1` и другие) и сохранять в `products_count`? Или только менять запросы, добавляя пересчёт и сохранение кол-ва?

Comment: [25.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Встроенного в MySQL решения я не нашёл, так что решил делать всё средстами програмнного кода.

Рядом с каждым запросом, который меняет `products` (изменяет статус строки, удаляет строку, добавляет строку) добавил пересчёт общего кол-ва и сохранение в отдельную таблицу `products_count`.

Время исполнения запроса сократилось с 1.5-2 секунд до 0.1с